# How to match a string's end using a regex pattern in Java?

Tags: java, regex

I want a regular expression pattern that will match with the end of a string.

I'm implementing a stemming algorithm that will remove suffixes of a word.

E.g. for a word 'Developers' it should match 's'.
I can do it using following code :

```
Pattern  p = Pattern.compile("s");
Matcher m = p.matcher("Developers");
m.replaceAll(" "); // it will replace all 's' with ' '
```

I want a regular expression that will match only a string's end something like `replaceLast()`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to match "s", but only if it is the last character in a word. This is achieved with the boundary assertion $:

```
input.replaceAll("s$", " ");
```

If you enhance the regular expression, you can replace multiple suffixes with one call to replaceAll:

```
input.replaceAll("(ed|s)$", " ");
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `$`:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("s$");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    String message = "hi this message is a test message";
    message = message.replaceAll("message$", "email");
    System.out.println(message);
}
```

Check this,
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/bounds.html

Answer (score 1):

When matching a character at the end of string, mind that the `$` anchor matches either the *very end of string* or the *position before the final line break char if it is present* **even** when the `Pattern.MULTILINE` option is not used.

That is why it is safer to **use `\z` as the very end of string anchor in a Java regex**.

For example:

```java
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("s\\z");
```

will match `s` at the end of string.

See a related [Whats the difference between \z and \Z in a regular expression and when and how do I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2707870/3832970) post.

**NOTE**: Do not use zero-length patterns with `\z` or `$` after them because [String.replaceAll(regex) makes the same replacement twice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8604286/3832970) in that case. That is, do not use `input.replaceAll("s*\\z", " ");`, since you will get two spaces at the end, not one. Either use `"s\\z"` to replace one `s`, or use `"s+\\z"` to replace one or more.

If you still want to use `replaceAll` with a zero-length pattern anchored at the end of string to replace with a single occurrence of the replacement, you can use a workaround similar to the one in the [How to make a regular expression for this seemingly simple case?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69649070/3832970) post (writing *"a regular expression that works with `String` `replaceAll()` to remove zero or more spaces from the end of a line and replace them with a single period (`.`)"*).