# How to make a regular expression for this seemingly simple case?

Tags: java, regex

Is it possible to write a regular expression that works with `String` `replaceAll()`  to remove zero or more spaces from the end of a line and replace them with a single period (`.`).

For example, a `regex` that will make these (non-exhaustive) test cases pass:

```
String regex = "????";
assertEquals("foo.", "foo".replaceAll(regex, "."));
assertEquals("foo.", "foo ".replaceAll(regex, "."));
assertEquals("foo.", "foo  ".replaceAll(regex, "."));
assertEquals(" foo.", " foo  ".replaceAll(regex, "."));
```

I know I can do it with `replaceFirst(" *$", ".")`, but I'm wondering if it can be done with `replaceAll()`.

UPDATED TO ADD:
The reason for the question is I was writing a data-driven chain of transformations and it only had `replace` and `replaceAll` as allowable transformations. I can do it in two `replaceAll` transformations. I just wondered if it were possible to do it one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an alternation based pattern that matches either one or more whitespaces at the end of string or an end of string that has no whitespace right before:

```java
 +$|$(?<! )
\h+$|$(?<!\h)
\s+$|$(?<!\s)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cFdeIs/1). `\h` matches horizontal whitespaces, and `\s` matches any whitespace chars.

Also, `$` can be replaced with `\z` to match the very end of string.

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/5QWfe4):

```java
String regex = "\\s+\\z|\\z(?<!\\s)";
System.out.println("foo.".equals("foo".replaceAll(regex, ".")));
System.out.println("foo.".equals("foo ".replaceAll(regex, ".")));
System.out.println("foo.".equals("foo  ".replaceAll(regex, ".")));
System.out.println(" foo.".equals(" foo  ".replaceAll(regex, ".")));
```

All test cases show `true` as output.

Comment: Ah, I see, using a negative lookbehind for the second alternative to prevent the double match.

Comment: Good point about using `\z` instead of `$`.

Answer (score 1):

You could make sure your "list of spaces" is preceded by "not a space":

```
(?<=\S)\s*$
```

To cover empty strings too:

```
(?<=\S|^)\s*$
```

Comment: That won't work for an empty string. I know that wasn't one of my test cases though!

Comment: @ᴇʟᴇvᴀтᴇ Ah yes indeed, I didn't think an empty string should become a single dot, you could still `(?<=\S|^)` if needed, updated.

Comment: This works and I've upvoted, but the lookbehind approach is slightly shorter.

Answer (score 1):

```
(?<!\s)\s*$
```

You could make sure your "list of spaces" is not preceded by "a space".

Instead of:
*You could make sure your "list of spaces" is preceded by "not a space"*

Because `(?<=\S)` (as character set) doesn't match an empty string, but `(?<!\s)` does.

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/H7u9gL/1)

Comment: Is it correct to add the final period when the last _non-space_ character is already a period?