# Regular Expression passes for one character sequence whereas fails for another

Tags: regex, perl

I am using the following regular expression:

```
$test="a\n";

if ($test =~ /^.$/ ){
 print "Test Passed\n";
}else{
 print "Test Failed\n";
}
```

For the aforementioned test variable, the regular expression finds the pattern.

However, if I change the variable to the following value it fails to identify the pattern.

```
$test="\na";
```

I know that my expression matches a single character i.e. the target should start and end with a single character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Concise answer**

If you need to check if a string has only one character (any, incl. newline), use

```
/^.\z/s
```

**Explanation**

The problem stems from the fact that you are using the `$` without `D` modifier, meaning that `$` matches at the end, but not at the very end of the string. Here, `$` = `\Z`.

By default, `$` will match the end of string and the position before the last newline. Thus, `a\n` passes the `if ($test =~ /^.$/ )` test, but `\na` will not, since `.` cannot match a newline, and it is not at the end, but at the start (it won't be matched with `if ($test =~ /^.$/ )` nor with `if ($test =~ /^.$/s )`).

Note that you can use `\z` anchor that will force the regex engine to match at the very end of the string. Then, both test cases even with a DOTALL modifier will fail. Use `/^.\z/` if you need that behavior. Or `/^.\z/s` to also match a single newline.

Also, see [*Whats the difference between \z and \Z in a regular expression and when and how do I use it?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2707870/whats-the-difference-between-z-and-z-in-a-regular-expression-and-when-and-how)

Comment: I didn't get why the first test case is passing, as there are two characters present in the input i.e. a **new line**, and a character **a**.

Comment: I have explained it. The `$` is `\Z`, matching right at the end, or before the last newline in the string. Your string `a\n` has 1 non-whitespace character and it is matched with `.`. Then, the `$` matches the position in front of the last newline. Bingo!

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems.

First, `$` does not match the end of the string.  In the absence of the `/m` flag, it is equivalent to `\Z`, which matches *either* at the end of the string or just before a newline character at the end of the string.

Almost always this is not what you intend and you should use `\z` which only matches at the end of the string.  Pretty much any code that uses

Secondly, `.` by default does not match any character.  Unless you supply the `/s` flag, it matches any character *but `\n`*.

So your regex `/^.$/` will match:

1. a single character that is not a newline, or
2. two characters, where the first is not a newline but the second is

To match a single character, use `/^.\z/s` (or just length($string) == 1).