# Java regex validate a string consisting of repeated sequences of comma separated digits enclosed in parentheses

Tags: java, regex

I have an input containing repeated pattern like this:

```
 (3,5)(6,7)(8,9).....
```

I am working on a regex to validate the above string pattern.

I tried:

```
Pattern.compile("\\((\\d+),(\\d+)\\)")
```

Comment: And? The regex seems to be ok more or less. What is the problem?

Comment: Use `Pattern.compile("(?:\\(\\d+,\\d+\\))+")`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew You either need to add `^` and `$`, or you need to clarify that it must be used with `matches()`, not `find()`.

Comment: Thanks it works, yes i wanted to match and not find()

Answer (score 1):

If you have a specific pattern that may repeat one or more times in a string, and you want to make sure your string only consists of the repeated occurrences of the same pattern, you may use

```
^(?:YOUR_PATTERN)+$
\A(?:YOUR_PATTERN)+\z
```

Note that `$` [also matches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57548474/3832970) before a final newline char, that is why `\z` anchor is preferred when you need to match the *very end* of the string.

If you allow an empty string use the `*` quantifier instead of `+`:

```
^(?:YOUR_PATTERN)*$
\A(?:YOUR_PATTERN)*\z
```

In this case, the `YOUR_PATTERN` is `\(\d+,\d+\)`, thus, the repeated sequence validating pattern will be `\A(?:\(\d+,\d+\))+\z`.

In  Java, you may omit the `^`/`$` and `\A`/`\z` anchors when validating a string with `.matches()` method since it requires a full string match:

```
boolean isValid = text.matches("(?:\\(\\d+,\\d+\\))+");
```

Or, decalre the `Pattern` class instance first and then create a matcher with the string as input and run [`Matcher#matches()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches())

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?:\\(\\d+,\\d+\\))+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
if (m.matches()) {
    // The text is valid!
}
```