# How to check if a RegEx matches all the target string?

Tags: regex, delphi, delphi-xe7

I need to check if a regex pattern matches with all the target string.

For example, if the pattern is `'[0-9]+'`:

- Target string `'123'` should result `True`
- Target string `'123' + sLineBreak` should result `False`

The code should looks like the following:

```
uses
  System.RegularExpressions;

begin
  if(TRegEx.IsFullMatch('123' + sLineBreak, '[0-9]+'))
  then ShowMessage('Match all')
  else ShowMessage('Not match all');
end;
```

I've tried `TRegEx.Match(...).Success` and `TRegEx.IsMatch` without success and I'm wondering if there is an easy way for checking if a pattern matches the whole target string.

I've also tried using `^ - start of line` and `$ - end of line` but without any success.

```
uses
  System.RegularExpressions;

begin
  if(TRegEx.IsMatch('123' + sLineBreak, '^[0-9]+$'))
  then ShowMessage('Match all')
  else ShowMessage('Not match all');
end;
```

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/MzzJkJ/1) you can find an online test demonstrating that if the target string ends with a new line, the regex still matches even using start/end of line.

Comment: Did you try using anchors? `^[0-9]+$`

Comment: @Thefourthbird: Yes but it doesn't always work, I've updated the example in the question

Comment: [Strings Ending with a Line Break](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) part explains why you should use `\z` instead of `$` to avoid getting match in the last example.

Comment: @BrakNicku: It seems that `\z` solves my problem, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the whole string matches:

```
\A[0-9]+\z
```

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \A                       the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [0-9]+                   any character of: '0' to '9' (1 or more
                           times (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \z                       the end of the string
```

Also, see [Whats the difference between \z and \Z in a regular expression and when and how do I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2707870)

Comment: Which is the difference between `\A` and `^` ?

Comment: I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4250094/4528159). +1 and thanks for your answer

Answer (score -5):

```js
var str = '123';
var sLineBreak = '\n';

console.log(str.match(/^\d+$/)); //123
console.log((str + 'b').match(/^\d+$/)); //123b
console.log((str + sLineBreak).match(/^\d+$/)); //123\n
```

You can use : `^\d+$`

`^`  start of string

`\d+` at lease one or more number of digits

`$`  end of string

Comment: When at least one must occur (as per `+`) you can't say "any".

Comment: Unfortunately, the regex still matches if the target string ends with a new line, I've updated the question by also adding an online test

Comment: That's not Delphi.